# gRPC "call already closed"

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

I recently upgraded to gRPC 1.55.1 from 1.44.0 and I started getting this stack trace

> May 29, 2023 7:33:36 PM io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor run
> SEVERE: Exception while executing runnable
>
> io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$1HalfClosed@6a59743a
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: call already closed
>
> at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:502)
>
> at io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl.closeInternal(ServerCallImpl.java:212)
>
> at io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl.close(ServerCallImpl.java:207)
> ...

Now the code itself actually runs it completes the request which is a simple health request.  The client already receives a success signal and terminates after making the call.  It is expected that the connection will be closed.

But this stack trace is filling up my log and I am not sure what is causing it.  The closest thing I can think of is to disable the log message using the following code but that seems a bit drastic.

```java
Logger grpcExecutorLogger = Logger.getLogger("io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor");
grpcExecutorLogger.setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

Is there a new way of implementing the server side that I may have missed in the release notes because I can't see anything obvious.

The full trace

```
SEVERE: Exception while executing runnable io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$1HalfClosed@56a7a5ef
java.lang.IllegalStateException: call already closed
       at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:502)
       at io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl.closeInternal(ServerCallImpl.java:212)
       at io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl.close(ServerCallImpl.java:207)
       at brave.grpc.TracingServerInterceptor$TracingServerCall.close(TracingServerInterceptor.java:120)
       at io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$ServerCallStreamObserverImpl.onCompleted(ServerCalls.java:395)
       at MYOWNSERVICE.SimpleGrpcHealthServiceImpl.check(SimpleGrpcHealthServiceImpl.java:22)
       at io.grpc.health.v1.HealthGrpc$MethodHandlers.invoke(HealthGrpc.java:326)
       at io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$UnaryServerCallHandler$UnaryServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ServerCalls.java:182)
       at brave.grpc.TracingServerInterceptor$TracingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(TracingServerInterceptor.java:153)
       at io.grpc.PartialForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(PartialForwardingServerCallListener.java:35)
       at io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ForwardingServerCallListener.java:23)
       at io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener$SimpleForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ForwardingServerCallListener.java:40)
       at io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl$ServerStreamListenerImpl.halfClosed(ServerCallImpl.java:346)
       at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$1HalfClosed.runInContext(ServerImpl.java:860)
       at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
       at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

I tried both the `HeatlhStatusManager.getHealthService()` implementation and my own that simply returns `SERVING` to try to diagnose this as well.

```
  @Override
  public void check(HealthCheckRequest request,
      StreamObserver<HealthCheckResponse> responseObserver) {
      HealthCheckResponse response = HealthCheckResponse.newBuilder().setStatus(SERVING).build();
      responseObserver.onNext(response);
      responseObserver.onCompleted();
    }
  }

  // for completeness but I don't call this method.
  @Override
  public void watch(HealthCheckRequest request,
      StreamObserver<HealthCheckResponse> responseObserver) {
      check(request, responseObserver);
    }
  }
```

The healthcheck client doesn't do anything special it simply makes the call and shuts down the connection when it's done.

```java
public class GrpcHealthCheckApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    var channel =
        ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1])).usePlaintext().build();

    var stub = HealthGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);
    var request = HealthCheckRequest.newBuilder().build();
    var response = stub.check(request);

    if (!response.getStatus().equals(HealthCheckResponse.ServingStatus.SERVING)) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Health-check failed");
    }
    channel.shutdown();
    channel.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
  }
}
```

Comment: You are probably closing the RPC multiple times (accidentally, or racing between threads). The stack trace would show the _second_ close.

Comment: I added the full trace but don't see anything specific about closing (except for half closed) near the bottom.

Comment: Is there any way your SimpleGrpcHealthServiceImpl.check() could be calling responseObserver.onCompleted() twice? Or call both onError() and onCompleted()?

Comment: I don't think so I'll post the code snippet

Comment: You mention that the client terminates.  Are you calling channel.shutdownNow() and awaitTermination in your client?

Comment: @LarrySafran yes I added the client code

Comment: check() looks good. Very little way to have a bug in that! I'll note it would be better to leave watch() unimplemented than implemented in that form; callers may immediately re-create the RPC when it completes. As unimplemented, callers could fall-back to check(). But that's unrelated. Since the service looks good, next I'd suspect an interceptor. The Brave TracingServerInterceptor looks fine. Especially look at any of your custom interceptors.